# Content on page keeps moving when hovering to display a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display some content when the mouse hovers over a photo. However, I am having a hard time doing this without moving the rest of the content on the page that is below the images. What are some possible solutions to display the content right under the top 3 images on hover without using `margin-top: -22%`?

Attached is a link to the site: http://aswanson.net/ConnectWithTrainingHomePage/MyHomePage.html

```
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyHomePage.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <img class="cnetheader" src="cnetheader.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="100%">

    <img class="searchBar" src="searchBar.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="50%">

    <img class="eCommerce" src="eCommerce.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="92%">

    <img class="freelancer" src="freelancer.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="100%">

    <img class="photoHeader" src="photoHeader.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="100%">

        <img src="photos2.png" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" usemap="#map" />

        <map name="map">

    <div class="photo1">
        <area shape="rect" coords="63,13,451,260" href="https://www.google.com" />

        <div class="photo1-content">
            Only show when hovering
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="photo2">
    <area shape="rect" coords="481,13,870,258" href="https://www.google.com" />
    <div class="photo2-content">
            Only show when hovering
    </div>
</div>

<div class="photo3">
    <area shape="rect" coords="900,12,1290,258" href="https://www.google.com" />
    <div class="photo3-content">
        Only show when hovering
    </div>
</div>

<div class="photo4">
    <area shape="rect" coords="60,300,450,545" href="https://www.google.com" />
    <div class="photo4-content">
        Only show when hovering
    </div>
</div>

<div class="photo5">
    <area shape="rect" coords="483,301,870,545" href="https://www.google.com" />
    <div class="photo5-content">
        Only show when hovering
    </div>
</div>

<div class="photo6">
    <area shape="rect" coords="899,300,1288,545" href="https://www.google.com" />
    <div class="photo6-content">
        Only show when hovering
    </div>
</div>
</map>

<img class="enterprise" src="enterprise.png" alt="cnetheader" height="100%" width="100%">

</body>
    </html>


.eCommerce{
    margin-left: 7%;
}

.photo1-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo1:hover .photo1-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.photo2-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo2:hover .photo2-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 44%;
}

.photo3-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo3:hover .photo3-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -22%;
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.photo4-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo4:hover .photo4-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.photo5-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo5:hover .photo5-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 44%;
}

.photo6-content{
    display: none;
}

.photo6:hover .photo6-content{
    display: block;
    margin-top: -1%;
    margin-left: 75%;
}

.enterprise{
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `position:absolute` and `top,bottom,left,right` properties